# jquery - how does my html call

Tags: jquery, html, css, rounded-corners

I have a jQuery plugin that gives a rounded corner. I got the library from here:(jquery.corner.js)

```
http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/
```

This is my HTML markup:

```
<div>
    <div>
      <strong >tab 1</strong> <a href="#">tab 2</a> <a href="#">tab 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I call my jQuery from html?

Comment: 74 questions, and you still haven't learned how this site works?

Comment: There are a lot of working examples on the page you've linked. Just look at their HTML source… Or in other words: RTFM!

Answer (score 3):

Initially you should either use an id or class used on your `<div>` tags, and then identify that in a jQuery call:

```
<style>
.box{
background-color: blue;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){
$('.box').corner();
});
</script>
<div>
<div class="box">
      <strong >tab 1</strong> <a href="#">tab 2</a> <a href="#">tab 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to call JQuery *from* HTML, because they're different languages.

JQuery is a Javascript library and althought you can insert javascript directly inside an html file it is not the most recommended as it is deprecated. Is better to  include an external file and import it as can be seen in this tutorial http://www.quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html

You should also give the div in that you want the effect an identifier so it could be called from Jquery more easily. In the HTML

ex:

```
<div class="stylebox"> content here  </div>
```

OR

```
<div id="box1style"> content here  </div>
```

Inside the Javascript (.js) file you can perfectly call the Jquery (provided you have included it before the file you are calling), you should also have had included previously the library jquery.corner.js, and paste the implementation using your css selector like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.stylebox').corner();
}
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#box1style').corner();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery it's a javascript library and so it's called within javascript. To use javascript in your HTML code you need to add a `<script>` element tag. And before you can use your jquery plugin you need to load both jquery and jquery plugin.

In [jquery Tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery) there are many examples on how to work with jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Just include that js in the code and add following code in script .

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    ​jQuery(​"#id1").corner();​​​
 });
​
```

Assign a ID to the div for which you want rounded corner.

```
<div id = "id1">
<div>
      <strong >tab 1</strong> <a href="#">tab 2</a> <a href="#">tab 3</a>
    </div>
</div>​​​
```

For more examples, refer : https://github.com/malsup/corner